# HTML5 Canvas - what happens when clip(), translate() and scale() are called consecutively?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How does the HTML5 canvas behave when one makes consecutive calls to `clip()`, `translate()` or `scale()`?

Answer (score 5):

## Clip()

### Many paths before calling clip()

If one draws more than one path between calling `beginPath()` and `clip()`, all the paths serve as separate clip regions.

So with this code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/enaupjh8/)):

```
// Clip
iContext.beginPath(); 
iContext.rect( 10, 10, 10, 10 );
iContext.rect( 30, 30, 10, 10 );
iContext.clip();

// Draw rect
iContext.beginPath();
iContext.rect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
iContext.fill();
```

The result will be:

[image: Two squares]

### Calling clip() many times

When calling `clip()` more than once (without calling `save()` and `restore()` between the calls, the resultant clip area is an **intersection** of all the clipping paths.

So this code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/gtbh4mjy/1/)):

```
// First Clip
iContext.beginPath();
iContext.rect( 10, 10, 30, 30 );
iContext.clip();

// Second Clip
iContext.beginPath();
iContext.rect( 30, 30, 30, 30 );
iContext.clip();

// Draw rect
iContext.beginPath();
iContext.rect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
iContext.fill();
```

Will result in this intersected clip region:

[image: One square, which is an intersection of the two rectangles in the code]

## Translate

Translate is cumulative.

So calling a `translate( 10, 10 )`, followed by `translate( 30, 30 )` will give an overall translation of `( 40, 40 )`.

So calling this code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/pj5yahhx/1/)):

```
// First Clip
iContext.translate( 10, 10 );
iContext.translate( 30, 30 );

// Draw rect
iContext.beginPath();
iContext.rect( 0, 0, 10, 10 );
iContext.fill();
```

will draw:

[image: A rect at 40, 40 - the sum of the two translation figures]

## Scale()

Scale is cumulative.

So calling `scale( 2, 2 )` twice, will give an overall scale of `(4, 4)`.

This code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/dubLuuow/1/)):

```
// First Clip
iContext.scale( 2, 2 );
iContext.scale( 2, 2 );

// Draw rect
iContext.beginPath();
iContext.rect( 0, 0, 10, 10 );
iContext.fill();
```

Will draw this:

[image: A square at 0,0 with dimensions 40,40 - the original 10,10 size was multiplied twice]

Comment: Interesting soliloque! You might add how to undo those operations. Clearing 1+ clips requires wrapping those clips in `context.save ...clip... context.restore` Clearing all accumulated transformations is done with `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`.

Comment: Great addition! But as it wasn't on the original question I guess your comment does it already.